# how can I integrate a jQuery Scrollbar UI element in this rails file

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

I have this file:
geoView.html.erb

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag  'application'%>
<body onload="initialize()">

 <div id="top_vendors"></div>
<div id="left_control_panel">
 <input type="button" onclick="getlistings();" value="Add Markers">
 <input type="button" onclick="clearMarkers();" value="Remove Markers">
</div>

<div id="mid_wrapper">
  <div id="map_canvas"></div>
  <div id="right_control_panel">
   <input type="button" onclick="getlistings();" value="Add Markers">
   <input type="button" onclick="clearMarkers();" value="Remove Markers">
  </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXsensor=false"></script>
```

My question is Id like to add a horizontal scrollbar widget from the jQuery Cupertino themed library to the div "top_vendors" here.

I looked at [this](http://www.railsdeveloper.net/2010/06/rails-and-jquery-how-to-integrate-jquery-ui-into-your-rails-app/) tutorial as a guideline however, I haevn't been successful

So far I have these steps in place:
1) Copied the jQuery minified library into my Assets/javascripts folder
2) Copied the jqueryUI library there too
3) Copied the Cupertino themed images into Stylesheets/images
4) Copied the jquery-ui-..custom.css file to the stylsheets folder
5) here is the head tag of my application.js file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>App0521</title>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->
<%= stylesheet_link_tag   'jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css', "application", :media =>  "all" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery-1.4.2.min.js ', 'jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js',"application" %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
```

Im still not seeing any scroll bar in my browser.

What am I missing?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to include all `CSS`s and `JS`s in your application.html.erb. You can configure Rails to include it for you..

`application.html.erb:`

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => :all %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

Save the `js` files in the `assets/javascript` folder and include them in the `application.js`

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui      #here you are including the jQUERY-UI
//= require_tree .
```

Also in your `application.js` you need to create the functions in a [unobtrusive way](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) (I think it is missing for you).

If you want to call the [slide](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/) in your ID `#top_vendors` for example:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#top_vendors" ).slider();
});
```

The same can be done for any other [jQuery-UI pluging](http://jqueryui.com/demos/).

I hope it helps...

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. Its still not working :(
All the above is in place. Any suggestions as to where I can start debugging this

Comment: Also any idea where I can get a tutorial for jquery + rails. It seems all the tutorials are for the older versions

Comment: try to add the library through [google API](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide). Add this line to your application.html.erb:  `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` instead of downloading it.

Comment: you can check is jQuery is loaded with the code: `if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') { alert("jQuery library is loaded!"); } else { alert("jQuery library is not found!");}`. Place this code in your `application.js`

Comment: Hey thank you. Yes, I can atleast tell now that the jQuery library is loading. As a matter of fact, it loads even without this line:"src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>‌​". Now just need to figure out why the html elements are not using Jquery

Comment: check the `page source` of the HTML generated by rails, just to make sure that it is generating the `<div id="top_vendors"></div>`. Sometimes the result is not the same... also make some tests with id selector, some examples [here](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

Comment: Thanks. One quick question I have is: If I want a particular theme of the jQuery UI, since Im no longer placing the files in my CSS and Javascript folders, how does Rails know what theme I want?

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED: The reason this wasn't working is because I did not embed this function inside the "$(document).ready(function()..." It works beautifully now - Thanks